# In Convolutional Neural Nets, what do the convolutions look like?

Tags: neural-networks

The early stages of the Convolutional Neural Networks are performing classical convolutions with a certain kernel size on the input image. Is is possible to express in common terms the type of filtering they are generally performing (lowpass, highpass, differential, anisotropic...), or are they completely application-dependent/impossible to interpret ?

Alternatively, can you show some sample kernel ? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Also asked on Signal Processing. My question is not a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2228779/65203

Comment: At first, a (layered non-recurrent) neural network is of the form $y_{j+1} = f(M_j y_j)$ with $y_j \in \mathbb{R}^{n_j},M_j \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{j+1}\times n_j}$ and $f$ is a smooth function acting component-wise (usually it is $\tanh$). $y_j$ is a function of the input $y_0$ and the $M_j$ (the parameters to be optimized in order to minimize the objective function). A convolution layer means replacing $M_j y_j$ by $h_j \ast y_j$, so the filter $h_j$ is now the parameter to be optimized, and hence it can be any kind of [FIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response).

Comment: What ? ${}{}{}$

Comment: This is what I just described.

Comment: ??? You can initialize $h_j$ with a LP filter and it can very well become a HP filter during the training. Similarly without any convolutional layer, the $M_j$ can very well become filter matrices (in real-life it doesn't happen often that's why convolutional layers are useful)

Comment: It is clear there is something you don't understand but you don't give any clue to find what it is, so..

Comment: See http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ it is about the architecture of the network/layers (ie. the dimensions and connectivity of $y_j,M_j,h_j$ and the choice of $f_j$ for short), the rest is created by the training algorithm. If you want to see a resulting optimized NN that works then it is clearly a different question, one way being to download working codes and plot $y_j, j = 1 \ldots 4$ (the image layers, before they become features for $j$ large).

Comment: @reuns: thanks for the do-it-yourself tip.

Comment: Ok... Have fun insulting thepeople trying to help you !

Comment: Take a look here to see visualized examples of learned filters:
https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/

Answer (score 1):

There are some attempts to figure out what a CNN learned. Most interesting to me is LIME:

> Marco Tulio Ribeiro, Sameer Singh, Carlos Guestrin: ["Why Should I Trust You?": Explaining the Predictions of Any Classifier](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04938)

Simplified a lot, they do the following:

1. Divide the image into superpixels (regions)
2. Feed the classifier with an image, where some superpixels are made black
3. Fit a much simpler model with the superpixel/classifier output.
4. Use that model to find the region which is relevant for the prediction

Another paper which is very famous for visualization is

> Matthew D Zeiler, Rob Fergus: [Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901)

Now to your other question:

> Is is possible to express [the learned convolution of other layers than the first one] in common terms the type of filtering they are generally performing (lowpass, highpass, differential, anisotropic...), or are they completely application-dependent/impossible to interpret ?

I haven't heard of any other, non-application dependent interpretation.